# How to describe $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)})$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Describe $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)})$, where $\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}$ is the localization at $\mathbb{C}[x]\setminus (x)$.

Does $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)})$ only consist of the generic point $(0)$ since $(x-a)$ is a unit after localization?

Comment: There is still one nontrivial prime ideal in $C[x]_{(x)}$

Comment: Prime ideals of $A_\mathfrak{p}$ correspond 1:1 to prime ideals of $A$ contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ (consult an arbitrary textbook on commutative algebra).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For any ring $R$ and multiplicatively closed set $S\subset R$, the prime ideals of $S^{-1}R$ are in bijection with the prime ideals of $R$ which do not meet $S$ (i.e. the prime ideals of $R$ whose intersection with $S$ is empty). Given a prime ideal $P$ of $S^{-1}R$, the corresponding prime ideal of $R$ is just $\varphi^{-1}(P)$ where $\varphi:R\to S^{-1}R$ is the natural map $\varphi(r)=\frac{r}{1}$.

Which prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ do not contain any elements of $\mathbb{C}[x]\setminus (x)$?

Comment: So $(x)$ is also a prime ideal in $c[x]_{(x)}$,right?